# не отображется даже стандартная постраничная навигация wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Столкнулся с проблемой, не отобрается даже стандартная постраничная навигация, возможно у вас есть подходящее решение ?

```
  <div class="content">
      <div class="grid">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" >
        <figure class="effect-lily">
          <?php the_post_thumbnail (); ?>

          <figcaption>
            <div>
              <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
              <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

            </div>                
          </figcaption>     
        </figure>
        </a>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
       <div class="page-nav">
          <div class="nav-previous">
            <?php previous_posts_link('Предыдущая') ?>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-next">
            <?php next_posts_link('Следующая') ?>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php else : ?>

        <?php endif; ?>           

      </div>
      </div>
```

Спасибо за понимание

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `next_post_link` вместо `next_posts_link` так как по описанию `next_posts_link` используется в шаблонах таксаномий, вот их сравнение
http://wp-kama.ru/function/next_posts_link и http://wp-kama.ru/function/next_post_link